# C# how to make class variable reference another value within the class

Tags: c#

I have the following simplified class:

```
public class Foo
{
     public DateTime dateOfBirth {get; set;}
     public Age age {get; set;}
}
```

and `Age` is as follows:

```
Public class Age
{
     public DateTime dateOfBirth {get; set;}    
     //..Calculate age here
}
```

Now, I want `Foo.Age.dateOfBirth` to equal `Foo.dateOfBirth` automatically eg when a user does the following:

```
var Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.dateOfBirth = //..whatever
```

Note, this cannot be in the constructor, as the user may not set the Dob in the constructor, and this would also not cover the situation where the Dob changes.

It needs to be a direct reference to the `dateOfBirth` variable.

Cant his be done?

Comment: Interesting. If `age` is public, why do you want to has a second `dateOfBirth` which is equal to `age.dateOfBirth`? You don't like typing long variable names?

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius it is just for illustration purposes. The dateofbirth is stored inside another variable within the class, and I will use this to set the date of birth and calculate the age of the person int he Age class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the setter:

```
public class Foo
{
    private DateTime _dateOfBirth;

    public DateTime DateOfBirth
    {
        get { return _dateOfBirth; }
        set {
            _dateOfBirth = value;
            if(Age != null)
               Age.DateOfBirth = value;
        }
    }

    public Age Age { get; set; }
}
```

If you would make the `DateOfBirth` property depend on the `Age` property it was easier, you could use the [C#6](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6) expression bodied readonly property:

```
public class Foo
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth => Age?.DateOfBirth ?? DateTime.MinValue;
    public Age Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This solution (the longer one) allows to set `Age.DateOfBirth` and thus break consistency. I like the short one, however.

Answer (score 3):

You should link the setter in Foo with the setter in Age. 
Try this:

```
public class Foo
{
 public DateTime dateOfBirth {
     get { return Age.dateOfBirth; }
     set { Age.dateOfBirth = value; }
 }
 public Age age {get; set;}

 public Foo() { Age = new Age(); }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Implement getter and setter of `dateOfBirth` to use the `Age` property. In contrast to most of the other answers, this one will make sure this property is always `!= null` and the two `DateOfBirth` properties are always consistent:

```
public class Foo
{
     public DateTime dateOfBirth
     {
         get{ return Age.dateOfBirth; }
         set{ Age.dateOfBirth = value; }
     }

     private readonly Age _age = new Age();
     public Age Age { get{ return _age; } }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be possible by using the below code,

```
public class Foo
{
     private DateTime _dateOfBirth;

      public DateTime dateOfBirth
      {
        get
        {
            return _dateOfBirth;
        }
        set
        {
            _dateOfBirth = value;
            this.Age.dateOfBirth = value;
        }
     }
     public Age age {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: This solution allows to set `Age.DateOfBirth` and thus break consistency.